# C++ set<T> What is the most appropriate solution?

Tags: c++, linked-list, set, generic-list, generic-collections

I couldn't get the use of Class or Struct using a C++ Set. I searched on the internet and stackoverflow, but i couldn't find a sample.
Classically, it seems impossible to find samples other than int and string samples, as a result of my calls. I wish a friend to help.

Thanks to the friends who will respond.

```
using namespace std;

struct DemoData
{
    int             id;
    string          Pairs;
    double          Price;

};

int main()
{
    DemoData myDemoDara  ;
    myDemoDara.id = 1; myDemoDara.Pairs = "GBPJPY"; myDemoDara.Price = 9.34;
    set<DemoData> setVeri  ;    //**It gives errors during compilation.**

    setVeri.insert(listem);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: When asking about build errors, always copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete error output from the compiler into the question itself.

Comment: As for what I ***guess*** the problem is, it's that you don't have an `operator<` function for your structure. [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is *ordered* (i.e. elements are sorted), and you need a less-than comparison operator (`operator<` overload) to compare the structures for the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to provide a custom `operator <` for your struct `DemoData`

```
struct DemoData
{
    int             id;
    string          Pairs;
    double          Price;
    bool operator < (const DemoData& other) const {
     return std::tie(   id, Pairs, Price) < 
            std::tie(   other.id, other.Pairs, other.Price) ;
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the working logic of this section?    
bool operator < (const DemoData& other) const {
     return std::tie(   id, Pairs, Price) < 
            std::tie(   other.id, other.Pairs, other.Price) ;
    }

Comment: @UmitTerzi `std::set<T>` is contains a sorted set of unique objects of type `T`. `std::set<T>` will use `std::less<T>` to compare the `DemoData`, `std::less<T>` uses the `operator<`, so your class has to provide this operator, since its not directly infered how you would want to compare two these object of `DemoData` and insert into the `std::set`. `std::tie` makes life easier to provide a strick weak ordering. You can search deatils on `std::set` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: **Thank you for the details. Even though I'd read so much, I didn't understand what was written on other sites.**